# Can a Corrupt Word Template be fixed?

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

We are just looking at upgrading from Office 2000 to Office 2010.

We have a fairly large number of in-house templates, most of which are enforcing house style and user information through auto text.   Macros are restricted to the Normal or Global templates, with one or two exceptions.

During our testing we have discovered problems with one set of documents with Word 2010.  Through the MS forums it has been confirmed that the base templates for these documents is corrupted.  It appears that the corruption has been present since the introduction of the templates.

We therefore have several hundred, if not more, documents that open and work in Word 2000, but will not work in Word 2010 (or Word 2007).

Short of opening all the documents in Open Office and re-saving them, is there anything we can do to recover the files?  (We always planned on recreating the templates from scratch for Office 2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we've discovered that we can "Save As" docx in Word 2000 using the Office 2007 compatibility pack and Word 2010 will ignore the corruption.

I've created a small Delphi app to do this across the network when we move over...